# batch script error - mkdir not working with fully qualified directory path

Tags: batch-file, mkdir

I'm trying to create directories at multiple levels in a shared network directory using batch scripting but it is not working when I give a fully qualified network path, rather it only works when I use mapped drive name. But I can't use mapped drive name as the production setup doesn't allow map drives. See examples below.

I'm trying to run this batch file but its failing with error message as ""

**mk_dir.bat**

```
@echo off
mkdir "\\hostname.com\shared_dir\Folder_Level_1\Folder_Level_2\Folder_Level_3\Folder_Level_4"
```

I have "\hostname.com\shared_dir" part of the path mapped to a drive 'U' and if I change my script as below, it works. But I don't want to use mapped drives like this.

**mk_dir.bat**

```
@echo off
mkdir "U:\Folder_Level_1\Folder_Level_2\Folder_Level_3\Folder_Level_4"
```

Can you please suggest a solution for this problem? Note I can't use powershell scripting.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for the commands [`pushd`](http://ss64.com/nt/pushd.html) and [`popd`](http://ss64.com/nt/popd.html):

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
pushd "\\hostname.com\shared_dir"
mkdir ".\Folder_Level_1\Folder_Level_2\Folder_Level_3\Folder_Level_4"
popd
endlocal
```

In case the shared directory might not exist, you should use this:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions
pushd "\\hostname.com\shared_dir" && (
    mkdir ".\Folder_Level_1\Folder_Level_2\Folder_Level_3\Folder_Level_4"
    popd
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but sorry this is not working. Getting the same error - "The directory or file cannot be created."

Comment: Of course you need to have sufficient access privileges to create folders there! Try to create folders in Windows Explorer to find out...

Comment: I have all the necessary permissions. I can create folders manually in windows explorer. I'm able to create directories via batch script but one level at a time and not all levels at once.

Comment: `mkdir` is capable of creating all the intermediate directories as long as the command extensions are enabled; if they are disabled, `pushd` does not accept UNC paths...